# PreferenceActivity Listpreference

Tags: android, preference, listpreference

I am writing a `PreferenceActivity` for my Android app. I have question about `ListPreference`.

How can I make a`ListPreference` that does an action if the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd string is selected? The XML looks like this:

```
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1000"
        android:dependency="perform_updates"
        android:entries="@array/Select_Shoe_Country"
        android:key="updates_interval"
        android:summary="Select Shoe"
        android:title="Example1" /> `
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need an `android:entryValues` array so that the system knows what each of the user's options means. Now, to directly answer your question, it may be easiest to launch an `Intent` based on the `android:entryValues` that is selected. Of course, it really depends on what exactly you want it to do.